# Flutter build runner ElementVisitor get path

Tags: flutter, dart, path, annotations, build-runner

I am working with `Code-Generation` and trying to get the `path` of the `Annotated-File`.

I would need it inside the `visitFieldElement`:

```
  @override
  dynamic visitFieldElement(FieldElement element) {
    // Get path here
  }
```

I tried couple of different things: `element.source`, `elenment.librarySource`, `element.location`.

But non of them is giving me the exact path relativ from `lib/`.

I know I can simply extract it from e.g the `element.location` but I thought there must be a cleaner way to get this done.

It should be possible since the `builder` itself is printing out the `path`:

[image]

Any idea? Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an element to  use via visiting children,
then I believe you do have the "buildStep" variable,
it contains the "path" variable and I think that is what you are looking for.